# How to enable snapping windows?

Tags: unity, 17.10, window-manager

When I drag a window to the size, I no longer get an option to snap it to the side and make its width be half of the screen. How can I restore that behaviour?

Using Unity on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Did you find entries in tweak-tools? p.s. don't waste time on ubuntu 17.10 - use 18.04 instead with its gnome-shell --> makes it much easier to configure with the  gnome extension.

Comment: gnome shell is buggy for me, I'm sticking with unity